# Is it possible to code Windows Mobile 7 using a Linux Environment?

Tags: windows, mobile, monodevelop

Is it possible to code Windows Mobile 7 using a Linux Environment ?
I have found the MonoDevelopement and I was wondering if this is achievable ?

Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: There is no Windows Mobile 7. Do you mean Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MonoDevelop for your development but Mono Team takes some time to port the latest additions in .Net Framework to Mono. Hence if you want to use the latest features, Mono would not be your best bet.

Comment: Thank you, I am looking to develop a Windows Mobile application. I think I will simply get a Virtual Machine set up, it will be my best solution.